# How to convert older SQL to latest one with IF condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand and re-write a query. The SQL style is something which I am not able to understand. Below is the query:

```
SELECT wc1.id AS category_id, wc1.name AS category_name,
        if(wc3.parent_id is not null, wc4.name, 
           if(wc2.parent_id is not null, wc3.name, 
              if(wc1.parent_id is not null, wc2.name, wc1.name))) as ultimate_parent
    FROM CATEGORIES wc1
    LEFT JOIN categories wc2 ON wc1.parent_id = wc2.id
    LEFT JOIN categories wc3 ON wc2.parent_id = wc3.id
    LEFT JOIN categories wc4 ON wc3.parent_id = wc4.id;
```

I am not able to understand the IF, IF, IF part of the query. This query is also giving me errors when I run it in Dbeaver - snowflake.
This is the first time I am seeing this type of IF conditions. And explanation and help in re-writing the query. The data is a simple parent - child relationship table.

What I am trying to do is:

```
SELECT wc1.id AS category_id, wc1.name AS category_name,
        if wc3.parent_id is not null then wc4.name, 
           if wc2.parent_id is not null then wc3.name, 
              else wc1.parent_id is not null Then wc2.name, wc1.name as ultimate_parent -- I am having issues with splitting the last if clause
    FROM CATEGORIES wc1
    LEFT JOIN categories wc2 ON wc1.parent_id = wc2.id
    LEFT JOIN categories wc3 ON wc2.parent_id = wc3.id
    LEFT JOIN categories wc4 ON wc3.parent_id = wc4.id;
```

Comment: Only MySQL supports `IF` (along with `CASE`). Most other databases use ANSI `CASE` statement for conditional logic expressions.

Comment: What error are you getting from the first query? The second query is invalid syntax as that form of if-then is not valid in a sql query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT wc1.id AS category_id, wc1.name AS category_name,
       (case when wc3.parent_id is not null then wc4.name 
             when wc2.parent_id is not null then wc3.name 
             when wc1.parent_id is not null then wc2.name
             else wc1.name
        end) as ultimate_parent
FROM CATEGORIES wc1 LEFT JOIN
     categories wc2 ON wc1.parent_id = wc2.id LEFT JOIN
     categories wc3 ON wc2.parent_id = wc3.id LEFT JOIN
     categories wc4 ON wc3.parent_id = wc4.id;
```